# htaccess 301 redirect is not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I would like to make a redirect from  http://www.jobslanda.com to http://www.jobslanda.com/

I'm trying to use this code in htaccess but it is not working.

```
Redirect permanent /http://www.alexandria-garagedoor.com http://www.alexandria-garagedoor.com/
```

Comment: Perhaps the code to redirect jobslanda.com shouldn't be referencing alexandria-garagedoor.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jobslanda\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.jobslanda.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```